# Stricky Profile Name top in android using scrollview

Tags: java, android, view

I have profile, with profile image, name, address and other user information and other data will be displayed on table view below. all this view added on scrolling view. If i started scolling up and if hide name or other, then name will be displayed on top as stricky.

please refer to this picture.
[image]

Please, if any other idea, such time of profile make , please share your idea, i really glad for this. It is just like google play when app load in different categories.and if you scolling bottom then  tab(top, top free) top stricky.